# Changing posts taxonomy after comment is posted

Tags: wordpress, hook

hello i am use a  comment_post action hook for Changing posts taxonomy after comment is posted, but my custom post type dont change the taxonomies.

can you help me please?

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'change_taxonomy' );
function change_taxonomy($post_id){
     $allow_show_comment = $_POST['c_comida'];
```

I set the array with the new taxonomies

```
     $terms = array();
     if($allow_show_comment){
        $terms[] = 'desayuno';
      }
      if($allow_show_comment2){
        $terms[] = 'almuerzo';
      }
      if($allow_show_comment3){
        $terms[] = 'cena';
      }
```

//mejorpara is my taxonomy

```
  wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, 'mejorpara', true);
}
```

Comment: What does `wp_set_object_terms` returns?

Comment: this cuntions is from the codex of wordpress and the function set new taxonomies to post, in this case must set (desayuno, almuerzo and cena ) like new taxonomy type mejorpara in post

Comment: I know what it does but check what it returns.

Comment: Sorry! i have the solutiion, I made a mistake, my function gets the ID of the comment, I was assigning taxonomies to comment. I needed the ID of the post 
$commentdata=get_comment($post_id, ARRAY_A); 
     $parent_post=get_post($commentdata['comment_post_ID']); $parent_post->ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution i need get the Id of post

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'change_taxonomy' );
function change_taxonomy($post_id){
     $allow_show_comment = $_POST['c_comida'];

    //get the ID of post
    $commentdata=get_comment($post_id, ARRAY_A); 
    $parent_post=get_post($commentdata['comment_post_ID']); 


     $terms = array();
     if($allow_show_comment){
        $terms[] = 'desayuno';
      }
      if($allow_show_comment2){
        $terms[] = 'almuerzo';
      }
      if($allow_show_comment3){
        $terms[] = 'cena';
      }
wp_set_object_terms( $parent_post->ID, $terms, 'mejorpara', true);
}
```